# onload de un objeto FileReader JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy realizando un curso y para cargar una imagen en un formulario se utiliza el siguiente codigo, el cual no explican muy bien y he buscado por internet pero no logro entender como funciona

```
let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = ((theFile) => {
                console.log(theFile);
                return (e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                    //Insertamos la imagen
                    document.getElementById('fotos').innerHTML = 
                    ['<img class = "responsive-img" src = "', e.target.result,
                '"title"', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                };

            })(f);
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
```

Lo que comprendo es que al leerse el archivo se activa el metodo anonimo de reader.onload y el parametro theFile es el archivo que se leyo, le hice un console log y puedo ver que sale informacion de la imagen como el nombre, tamaño entre otras cosas, pero  no comprendo el parametro e de return, al hacerle console log igual me muestra informacion mas detallada de la imagen pero no comprendo por qué o como funciona, el codigo funciona bien pero quisiera comprender como funciona ese return, tampoco comprendo por que al final esta como parametro la variable f, a que funcion le está llegando como parametro?

Comment: si colocas todo el codigo te podria dar un mejor explicacion!

Answer (score 1):

**Primero:** hay un error en el html que se concatena (que no es la manera correcta de hacerlo por demás).

```
[
  '<img class = "responsive-img" src = "', 
  e.target.result,
  '"title"', // debiera ser '" title="'
  escape(theFile.name),
   '"/>'
].join('');
```

Formaría un tag de la forma:

```
  <img class = "responsive-img" src = "data:image/png;base64,ASDFG"title"miarchivo.png"/>
```

Pero debiera ser

```
  <img class = "responsive-img" src = "data:image/png;base64,ASDFG" title="miarchivo.png"/>
```

Por otro lado, en vez de concatenar tú mismo el HTML, es más elegante pedirle al DOM que lo haga por tí:

```
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = e.target.result;
      img.title = theFile.name;
      document.getElementById('fotos').appendChild(img);
```

**Dicho esto,** el API [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) de HTML5 tiene entre otras características:

- métodos para leer objetos de tipo [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File) como por ejemplo [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)
- handlers (manejadores de eventos) que, de ser declarados, luego de instanciar el FileReader, se invocarán usando como parámetro el evento al que escuchaban

  - un handler como `onload` recibe un evento con el resultado de la lectura. Si esa lectura fue mediante `readAsDataURL` naturalmente el evento contiene un dataURI. Si se hubiera leído como binario tendría en cambio acceso byte por byte al contenido.
  - otros handlers reciben otro tipo de evento. Por ejemplo `onerror` no tiene el contenido del archivo sino el mensaje y stack del error que se haya producido

    - Otros métodos que son irrelevantes en esta pregunta

Tradicionalmente, el flujo es instanciar el FileReader, declarar la función handler para el evento `onload`, leer un archivo, (se gatilla el handler), dentro del handler hacer algo con el archivo (moverlo a un div, subirlo al backend, etc)

```
// Flujo clásico
let theFile=<archivo leído desde el input>,
    reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload=function(e) {
   // hacer algo con e.target.result, que es el contenido base64
};
reader.readAsDataURL(theFile);
```

En tu código, como se requiere disponer del **nombre** del archivo (para dar el atributo `title` a la imagen) y el evento `e` no lo trae, usan el truco de declarar el handler como una función que recibe el archivo y devuelve el verdadero handler, que queda esperando.

Esto podría expresarse como

```
/**
* @param  {File}  fileObject un objeto File, valga la redundancia
*/
function generaOnloadHandler( fileObject ) {
    return function(e) {
        console.log({
            contenido: e.target.result,
            nombre: fileObject.name;
        });
    }
}

// Y más abajo
reader.onload=generaOnloadHandler(theFile) // devuelve el handler generado
```

Todo esto es quizá demasiado elaborado, ya que, al estar declarado en el mismo contexto que el fileReader, el handler sí tiene acceso al nombre del archivo, porque `f` es una [variable libre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934929/what-are-free-variables).

Bastaría con hacer:

```
 reader.onload = (e) => {
    console.log({
            contenido: e.target.result,
            nombre: f.name;  // accedo directo a f
    });
 };
 reader.readAsDataURL(f);
```

Pero si nos ponemos elaborados, se puede usar el hecho que un closure es "*bindeable*". Podemos pasarle un contexto y de ahí en adelante ese closure considerará que `this` es el contexto que le pasamos.

```
 reader.onload = (function (e) {
    console.log({
            contenido: e.target.result,
            nombre: this.name;  // `this` es f, porque quedó bindeada a ese contexto
    });
 }).bind(f);
```

*Ojo: Esto no funciona si en vez de* `(function(e) {..})` *intentas usar* `(e=>{ ... })`

Te dejo los tres enfoques como un snippet:

```js
const inputOnloadClasico = document.getElementById("onload_clasico"),
  inputOnloadGenerado = document.getElementById("onload_generado"),
  inputOnloadBinded = document.getElementById("onload_binded"),
  divFotos = document.getElementById("fotos");

inputOnloadClasico.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let files = event.target.files,
    reader = new FileReader(),
    f = files[0];

  reader.onloadend = (e) => {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = e.target.result;
    img.title = f.name;
    divFotos.appendChild(img);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);

}, false);




inputOnloadGenerado.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let files = event.target.files,
    reader = new FileReader(),
    f = files[0];

  reader.onload = ((theFile) => {
    return (e) => {
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = e.target.result;
      img.title = theFile.name;
      divFotos.appendChild(img);
    };
  })(f);
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);

});

inputOnloadBinded.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  let files = event.target.files,
    f = files[0],
    reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = (function(e) {
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = e.target.result;
    img.title = this.name; // WHAAAT como "this.name"?
    divFotos.appendChild(img);
  }).bind(f); // binding magic

  reader.readAsDataURL(f);

}, false);
```

```css
#fotos {
  padding: 5px;
}

#fotos img {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family:monotype;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 120px;
  text-align:right;
  margin-right:5px;
}
input {
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-radius:4px;
min-width:340px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>onload clásico:</label><input type="file" id="onload_clasico" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>onload generado:</label><input type="file" id="onload_generado" />
</div>
<div>
  <label>onload binded:</label><input type="file" id="onload_binded" />
</div>
<div id="fotos"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando define el método que se ejecutará en el `onload` está haciendo uso del **IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression)** que es una función que se autollama inmediatamente luego de haberla declarado.

En tu código el IIFE sería esto `((thefile) => { ... })(f) <-- invocación inmediata como parametro el fichero que has leído`

Como dicho IIFE devuelve una función pues esta función es la que se asigna a la propiedad `onload` del reader. 
Que pasaría a ser esto luego de haberse ejecutado el IIFE.

```
reader.onload = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        //Insertamos la imagen
        document.getElementById('fotos').innerHTML = 
        ['<img class = "responsive-img" src = "', e.target.result,
    '"title"', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
    };

El parametro `e` es el que le pasa JS cuando ha leído el fichero.
```

[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)